# How to resume couchbase lite iOS replication task on push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to temporarily resume (un-suspend?) my replication tasks in couchbase lite iOS when my app receives a push notification.  I've tried the following in my AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  NSLog(@"notification-body => %@", notification);

  NSMutableArray *toSuspend = [NSMutableArray array];

  CBLManager *manager = [CBLManager sharedInstance];
  for (NSString* name in [manager allDatabaseNames]) {
    CBLDatabase* db = [manager databaseNamed:name error:nil];
    NSArray* replications = [db allReplications];
    for(CBLReplication* rep in replications) {
      if(rep.suspended) {
        [rep setSuspended: NO];
        [toSuspend addObject: rep];
      }
    }
  }

  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(20 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"notification-complete => %@", notification);
    for(CBLReplication* rep in toSuspend) {
      [rep setSuspended: YES];
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
  });
}
```

But the list of replicators is always empty even though I have 2 running.  What am I doing wrong?